# Hiding submenu items of a page in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, routes

Is there a way, in Drupal 6, to automatically hide all submenu pages? For example, suppose I have the following menu structure:

- Sport

  - football
  - cricket

Is there a way I can enforce "football" and "cricket" to never be seen?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Menu Block module to only show the top level items: http://drupal.org/project/menu_block

Make a normal menu, create a menu block using that menu and set the depth to '1' .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default block created by the Menu system, you can control visibility at a global level under Site Building -> Menus -> List Menus -> [the menu in question], then either choosing to disable the particular link, or by disabling the 'Expanded' checkbox for the parent menu item.